# How to apply fourier transform on wav file

Tags: python

I've written a python script that finds the fourier transform of a sinusoidal wave input. I've done this manually because I found it interesting. The program works so long as a input a sine or cosine function with a given frequency. I've even tried a wave with 2 frequencies and it works. In a more realistic setting however, someone would not have access to the sinusoidal function, and instead would have a wav file for example. How could I extract or find a sinusoidal function from a wav file that I could input into my fourier transform python script?

Comment: please, tell us what have you tried and what exactly did not work (expected output, actual output etc.) ?

Comment: So my current python script accepts a sinusoidal function as its input. I've created functions with 2 frequencies, and the script was able to find those frequencies. But in real world applications, I'm assuming you wouldn't know the sinusoidal function because then you could easily find the frequencies. So I want to have lets say a wav file as the input. I need a way to get the sinusoidal wave from the wav file so I can apply the math to the values and find the frequencies.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I just did not realize that the wav file was already comprised of a sinusoidal function. I just had to input its values and find the integral based off of those values.